# mysql_info() equivalent in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm looking for a `mysql_info()` equivalent in Python.
My script executes a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement and I would like to have information like this :  `Records: 3 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0`.

I looked inside the Connector/Python API Reference but I didn't found anything.

Is there a way to get that information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connector/Python does not have a method directly showing the required info, but you can in a way(not a good way) get the required info.

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(...)
result =  conn.cmd_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query")
print (result['info_msg'])
```

Comment: I usually use a cursor to execute my queries but It seems that your technique is the only way to get that info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Module MySQLdb has `conn.info()`: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use only the official MySQL connector "Connector/Python", not a third-party module.